Convergence of not necessarily independent random variables from geometric distribution
Let $Y_1, Y_2,...$ be identically distributed (can be dependent) random variables, $Y_k \sim G(1/2)$ (geometric distribution with parameter $1/2$), so $P(Y_i = k) = \frac{1}{2^k}, k = 1,2,...$ . Lets define random variables $X_1, X_2,...$ by the following: $X_n = 2^{Y_n}I_\left({2\log_{2}n, \infty}\right)(Y_n), n = 1, 2,...$ . Does the sequence $X_n$ converge (to some random variable)? 1) almost surely? 2) by probability? 3) in $L_p$ space, $p \geq 1$? 4) by distribution?
My reasoning so far:


By the first Borel-Cantelli lemma we get $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(Y_n \geq 2\log_2{n})=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{n^2}<\infty \Longrightarrow \{Y_n \geq 2\log_{2}(n)\} \: \text{occurs finitely many times almost surely.}$$ Thus $X_n \xrightarrow{a.s} 0, (n \rightarrow \infty).$
and 4.
$1. \Rightarrow$
The finite $p$-th moment for $p\geq1$ is $\mathbb{E}\left(\vert X_n \vert^p \right)=\sum_{k=2\log_2{n}}^{\infty} 2^{(p-1)k}$ which diverges, thus $\mathbb{E}\left(\vert X_n \vert^p \right)=\infty$. Does not converge in in $L_p$ space, $p \geq 1$.


I don't see where the possible dependence of the random variables comes into play. What am I missing?

Is the point not that the result becomes more general due to the lack of an independence hypothesis? +1 for nice reasoning/answers

I think you're right. I don't see any argument of my proof affected by the possible dependence.

It is possible that the possible dependence does not play any role. For example, if $Z_n=\mathbf{1}_{A_n}$ and $\sum_n \mathbb P(A_n)<\infty$, then $Z_n\to 0$ almost surely, no matter the dependence of the sequence of events $(A_n)$.
